# Flaw in my argument that $[T]_{B} = [T]_{B'} \implies B = B'$

Tags: linear-transformations, change-of-basis, similar-matrices

I am currently self-studying linear algebra from Anton's *Elementary Linear Algebra*, and have come across the following question while working through the exercises: let $B$ and $B'$ be two bases for $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and let $T:\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a linear operator. If $[T]_{B} = [T]_{B'}$, is it true that $B = B'$?

This is false since the identity operator provides a counterexample for any choice of bases. However I can't reconcile how this is consistent with the following theorem, which has been stated without proof. Essentially, it says the following (though I am summarising):

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space, and suppose that the matrices $A$ and $B$ are similar with $B = P^{-1}AP$. Then $A$ and $B$ represent the same linear operator on $V$ (possibly with respect to different bases), and $P$ is the transition matrix from the basis used for $B$ to the basis used for $A$.

My argument for the claim  $[T]_{B} = [T]_{B'} \implies B = B'$ is as follows – can anyone help me spot the flaw? I feel I am misunderstanding the theorem.

> Let $B = \{v_{1}, v_{2}, \ldots, v_{n}\}$ and $B'=\{w_{1}, w_{2}, \ldots, w_{n}\}$ be two bases for $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and suppose that $[T]_{B} = [T]_{B'}$ for some linear operator $T$. Then 
>   $$[T]_{B} = [T]_{B'} = I^{-1}[T]_{B'}I,$$ 
>   so it follows from the theorem that $I$ is the transition matrix from $B$ to $B'$. Thus
>   $$[v_{1}]_{B'} = I[v_{1}]_{B} = [v_{1}]_B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, $$
>   and so $v_{1} = w_{1}$. Similarly $v_{i} = w_{i}$ for each $i \in \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$, so $B = B'$.

---

**Edit:** The full statement of the theorem in the book is as follows:

> **Theorem 8.5.3** If $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space, then two matrices $A$ and $B$ represent the same linear operator (but possibly with respect to different bases) if and only if they are similar. Moreover, if $B = P^{-1}AP$, then $P$ is the transition matrix from the basis used for $B$ to the basis used for $A$.

Comment: If you have a counterexample, substitute your counterexample into the proof and see where the first false statement about your counterexample is. (It turns out you're right, you're misunderstanding the theorem a bit.)

Comment: I see, I will think on this. Is the theorem correct as I have written it? I'm not confident about the line 'and $P$ is the transition matrix from the basis used for $B$ to the basis used for $A$'

Comment: Obviously not. Suppose $T$ is zero in a vector space of dimension at least one, and take two different bases there, then complete both of these with the same vectors into a basis of the whole space.

Comment: The theorem is correct as you have written it, but its wording may have encouraged you to make a subtle conceptual error related to the use of the term "the" transition matrix.

Comment: As an example unit vectors N and E for one basis and unit vectors NE and NW for the other. The matrix I is the identity transformation in both, but that does not mean the two bases are equal.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Unfortunately I still can't pinpoint the conceptual error. Could you please elaborate in an answer if you get the chance?

Comment: Can you please put up the full statement of the theorem. I suspect the problem is something missed in the summary.

Comment: @Peter Sure, I have edited the full statement into the bottom section of my question

Comment: Thanks for that. As I see it the problem is that sometimes many different bases can be used with the same transformation and matrix. The final sentence seems to imply uniqueness of basis, which is sometimes not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theorem you've cited can be reformulated as follows. Let $P$ be the transition matrix between the basis $\beta'$ used for $B$ and the basis $\beta$ used for $A$. Let $T$ be a linear transformation, and let $[T]_\beta$ be represented by matrix $A$. Then the matrix $P^{-1} A P$ represents $[T]_{\beta'}$.

Note however, $P^{-1} A P = A$ (in your case, $P^{-1} B P = B'$) does not imply that $P = I$. Indeed, for every basis $\beta'$ with $[T]_{\beta'} = [T]_\beta$ this is true for the matrix $P$ whose column vectors are the vectors of $\beta$. What your proof shows is that if the transition matrix is $I$ (namely $\beta = \beta'$), then $[T]_\beta = [T]_{\beta'}$ (and this is of course trivial).

So to point out the specific incorrect statement, it would have to be "so it follows from the theorem that $I$ is *the* transition matrix from $B$ to $B'$." This is incorrect. Instead, the only statement you can make is "$I$ is one of the possible transition matrices from $B$ to $B'$." Hope this helps!

Comment: I think the issue is that for some transformations, eg the identity transformation, there are multiple bases in which the same matrix gives the same transformation. So there are examples where P=I does not imply the bases are equal. Your reformulation solves this issue.

Comment: Ah I think I understand now. As Peter commented and as you use in your answer, there may be multiple bases that give the same matrices representing the transformation. Thanks!